# How do you disconnect from the MQTT broker using a button on VB

Tags: vb.net, mqtt

This is my code

```
Imports System
Imports uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt
Imports uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Messages
Imports System.Text.Encoding

Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Private i As Integer = 0
    Private Publisher As MqttClient = Nothing
    Private Subscriber As MqttClient = Nothing
    Private msgTime As String = ""
    Private msgDate As String = ""
    Const TIME_ID As String = "/CPM/Time"
    Const DATE_ID As String = "/CPM/Date"
    Const MATH_ID As String = "3.14"
    Const DefaultInteger As Integer = 100
    Const MyLong As Long = 45L
    Const MySingle As Single = 45.55!
    Const MyCharacter As Char = "a"c
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Publisher = New MqttClient("telemetry")
        Dim b As Boolean = CBool(Publisher.Connect(Guid.NewGuid.ToString))
    End Sub



    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Subscriber = New MqttClient("telemetry")
        Dim b As Byte = Subscriber.Connect(Guid.NewGuid.ToString)
        Button1.Enabled = False
        Subscriber.Subscribe(New String() {DATE_ID, TIME_ID}, New Byte() {MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE, MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_AT_LEAST_ONCE})
        'Subscriber.Subscribe(New String() {TIME_ID}, New Byte() {MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE})
        AddHandler Subscriber.MqttMsgPublishReceived, AddressOf Client_recievedMessage
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Client_recievedMessage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MqttMsgPublishEventArgs)
        Dim s As String = System.Text.Encoding.[Default].GetString(e.Message)

        Select Case e.Topic
            Case DATE_ID
                msgDate = s
            Case TIME_ID
                msgTime = s
        End Select

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

I want to add a disconnect at the button2_click function to disconnect from the broker. It is connecting to the telemetry broker when I click subscribe, but I want to disconnect when I press on button 2. How would I do this in MQTT

Answer (score 1):

```
Publisher.Disconnect()
```

Pretty straight forward...

https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt/MqttClient/Disconnect/php-mqttclient-disconnect-method-examples.html